# Use ROS_ macro to output std::vector data

Tags: ros, logger, log4cxx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I'm dealing with [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) data in C++ and I'd like to print it on the output stream (e.g. for debugging), I'm going to do something like this:

```
std::cout << "Data Retrieved: \n";
std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, " "));
std::cout << std::endl;
```

How to reproduce this behaviour using (for example) `ROS_DEBUG_STREAM()` macro?
I wish to include logger level also in the output of vector data.

The only way I found to achieve this result is something as follows:

```
log4cxx::LoggerPtr logger = log4cxx::Logger::getLogger(ROSCONSOLE_DEFAULT_NAME);
if (logger && logger->getLevel() == log4cxx::Level::getDebug()) {
  // debugging code
  std::cout << "Data Retrieved: \n";
  std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

In which case I need to link the proper library:

```
find_library(LOG4CXX_LIBRARY log4cxx)
target_link_libraries(some_target ${LOG4CXX_LIBRARY})
```

(I found these useful info [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/50392/accessing-log-level-in-roscpp/))

Someone knows if there is a better way?
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206617/use-ros_-macro-to-output-std::vector-data/) by [alextoind](https://answers.ros.org/users/20595/alextoind/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2015-04-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A typical solution is to create a `std::stringstream` object and build the output in a `for` loop. If you want this to be done conditionally make a function that does this and use it inside the ROS_DEBUG_STREAM call so it will be conditionally evaluated.

Note: Your solution is does not achieve the same result, It only goes to console. The rosconsole macros can go to both console as well as rosout.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alextoind](https://answers.ros.org/users/20595/alextoind/) on 2015-04-06**:
Thank you, I didn't think about that! Now works as expected.